# Asp.net 4.5 CORS Issues

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cors

I have an ASP.Net 4.5 application that is being used by several customers. The application is opened in an iframe. At the moment, application is working fine on chrome, but IE is giving a 500 error message for all ajax requests to the server. We used to get the same error message in chrome until we made some CORS changes.
Here are the changes that were made to the APP.
URL rewrite:

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Add Secure" preCondition="No Secure">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; Secure" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="No SameSite">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=None" negate="true" />
      </preCondition>
      <preCondition name="No Secure">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; Secure" negate="true" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This was added to AppSetting:

Session State

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" cookieSameSite="None" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" ...>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <!-- THESE HEADERS ARE IMPORTANT TO WORK WITH CORS -->
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://yourwebsite.com/error/500" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, name" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```